# After I set dataUrl to text area as value, browser and my site stop responding

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, data-uri, jszip

I am now trying to set the dataUrl of JSZip to textarea using `document.getElementById('fileContent').value = fileData;` . But Once I did that, the site and browser became no response without any error. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong? Please really need help, and thanks for reading my question.

- Every Thing goes well except after `document.getElementById('fileContent').value = fileData;`
- Even I copy the DataURL and paste it into the textarea by myself, my site and browser stopped eventually.
- I want to set the value inside a form element with action to send data by input value.

```
<textarea placeholder="Example Text" id="fileContent" name="fileContent" data-name="fileContent" class="w-input" spellcheck="false"></textarea>

<script>
function getfile() {
  var zip = new JSZip();

  for(let i = 0; i < file.length; i++){
      var caltor = i+1;
      var aFileName = "image"+caltor+".jpg";
      var aContent = dataURItoBlob(file[i]); 

      zip.folder("Image_folder").file(aFileName, aContent)
  }
  zip.generateAsync({type:"base64"})
  .then(function (content) {
      fileData = "data:application/zip;base64,"+content;
      document.getElementById('fileContent').value = fileData;
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: dataurls are normally very long and this might be causing the browser to unresponsive. try to console.log it and check the same behavior is occurring

Comment: It seems `document.getElementById('fileContent').value = fileData;` is not the best way to do what I want to do. It works if I use console.log to call the variable of storing the dataURL. But if I want to send dataURL by form submit method. Is there any better way to do it? BTW thank you for trying to answer my question.

Comment: Some browsers have a limit of size support in textarea, mostly 64 kb or something. see this link http://jkorpela.fi/forms/textarea.html#:~:text=Some%20browsers%20impose%20some%20limits,the%20rows%20and%20cols%20attributes.

Comment: if thats the case, instead of form submission send the zip to server using a xhr request

Comment: Use AJAX and a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). If you can change your server side code, then even send this file's content as binary directly (i.e don't read it as data:// URL at all, but pass directly the File or Blob object). If you really can't (that will cost you 34% of the file's size in bandwidth + 268% in memory) then still use a FormData and append your data:// URI there.